# maximum number of uprobe using bcc/bpf

Tags: linux-kernel, trace, bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I use bcc to trace userspace program with uprobe.
However, I cannot attach more than 500 uprobe.

I am wondering is there a limit of how many uprobe can be attached at the same time?
Or is there a kernel config that I can change?